# Не корректно работает mysql запрос

Tags: php, mysql

здравствуйте, есть элементарный запрос, с помощью которого можно ограничить количество публикаций раз в 10 минут:

```
    if(!empty($db->getOne("SELECT id FROM topics WHERE ip = ?s AND 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(INTERVAL -10 MINUTE + CURRENT_DATE()) < timestamp",
  $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"])) && $_POST['type'] == 1) $r[] = questioninterval;
```

Но дело в том что он работает как-то не правильно, я не могу открыть новую тему через ~15 минут, пишет про интервал. Зато могу через n часов, вроде бы, так как добавлял тему через пару часов, и данная проверка не срабатывала

Не подскажите что не так в коде?

Comment: `CURRENT_DATE()` возвращает только дату, т.е. 0 часов 00 минут с данной датой. Используйте `NOW()`

Comment: а вам правда удобно выполнять и проверять результат запроса в if-е еще и && к нему приплетая?

Comment: @teran Ну ТС же удобно все условия в SQL писать задом наперед, так что сразу и не догадаешься где столбцы, а где что. так что думаю и остальное удобно. Думаю магистр еда должен писать примерно так же :)

Comment: Тут сложно сказать какая у вас потом логика идет. проверьте для начала сам запрос в MySQL подставляя разные параметры, выберите кроме id еще и timestamp и то же от `now() - interval 10 minute` убедитесь что там именно те числа, которые вы ожидаете.

Comment: @Mike не знаю кому что не нравится, но код работает, и все нормально. Спасибо, замена на now() помогла, можете добавить новый ответ, я поставлю галочку. Возможно кому-то тоже пригодится разъяснение

Comment: @Владимир Ну проверку `$_POST['type'] == 1` я бы в if все таки делал первой, что бы когда это не так запрос в БД уже не посылался (`&&` не проверяет последующих условий (и не выполняет код) после первого же ложного условия). По поводу now() и current_date() думаю подобных ответов должна быть масса, только их все равно найти невозможно. потому что корректного поискового запроса придумать нельзя. так что вряд ли кто то столкнувшийся с той же проблемой найдет и этот вопрос ...

Comment: @Mike на счёт поменять местами, согласен. Просто писал код под утро, полу сонный, уже сразу же это сделал. Ещё раз спасибо за ответ.